# The nearest possible integer to the set $\{x+2\pi k | k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ less than $n$

Tags: optimization, algorithms

In a problem I am solving, I want to find a quick way or a basic formula to find the nearest integer less than $n$, the problem is stated as follow:

> Le $n$ be a positive integer, and let $x$ be a real number.
>     I am searching to find $m$ the nearest integer for the formula $x + 2k\pi$ ($k$ is an integer greater or equal 0) that is less than $n$.

An example, if $n = 21$ and $x = 1.2$ then $k=3$ and $m = 20$.

Beside testing all the values of $k$ I don't seem to find a better solution.

Comment: Does [floor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) do the trick for you? Apply it to $k = \frac{1}{2\pi} (n-x)$.

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk no it does not :(, in the example stated in the question if we take n=30, with your formula k=4 and m=26, but the correct answer is k=3 and m=20